# Can I write HTML code to Window.showModalDialog()?

Tags: javascript, html

I use :

```
Window.showModalDialog(...)
```

to open a dialog window,

I want show some HTML code in this window, but I don't have a file. (Can't use URL to visit)

like show "hello world!" in this dialog window.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question!

I'm not an expert in modal dialogs, but I don't think you can, because it's in the nature of a modal dialog to block any further code from being executed until the window is closed again.

I thought about using a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) that you could use as the first argument to `showModalDialog` instead of a normal URL:

```
 window.showModalDialog("data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ%3D%3D" ....);
```

but according to the [MSDN page on data: URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(VS.85).aspx), that will not be supported in Internet Explorer. (see the "Remarks" section on the linked page)

It might work in Firefox, though: [More on data URIs at Mozilla Developer Central](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_data_URL_scheme)

> **Update:** It works in Firefox: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27yeT/) but, as expected, not in IE. You only get a blank window there.

Answer (score 0):

Good question and answer. (+1)

I just thought I'd add, that if you *do* need to enter HTML into a modal dialog, you may want to look into using a Javascript library to accomplish it.  I've used Dojo's "`dijit.Dialog`" several times with HTML, including images, form controls etc... You can style it however you like, and it works well cross-browser.

You can check out a few example of `dijit.Dialog`'s use over at [DojoCampus](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Dialog).

Cheers.